# How can I send terminal escape sequences through SSH with Go?

Tags: bash, ssh, go, tty

I'm writing a Go program that will connect to a host via SSH using the native [x/crypto/ssh](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh) library and drop an interative shell.

I'm using [`RequestPty()`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.RequestPty), but the (bash) shell on the remote end does not behave as expected with control codes.

When I enter various control characters, they're echoed back by my terminal:

```
$ ^[[A
```

The characters still *work* in the sense that if I press enter after pressing the up arrow, the previous command is run - but the control character output clobbers what should be displayed there. The same goes for tab.

Is there some straightforward way to get this to work? When I've implemented similar systems in the past it hasn't been an issue because I've just shelled out to `openssh`, and the semantics of process groups sort it all out.

I've studied "[The TTY Demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)" and as great as it is it's not clear where to begin.

A couple of things I've thought to investigate:

- [enable raw mode in my terminal](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal#MakeRaw) - but I don't want to do this without understanding why, and it doesn't *seem* to do the right thing
- [fiddle with the terminal mode flags](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#pkg-constants)

`openssh` itself must be doing this work correctly, but it's a real best of a code base to study.

It's not actually clear to me whether this printing is being done by my local terminal emulator or shell or by the code on the remote host.

Where do I begin?

---

Here is a sample of my code:

```
conf := ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: myuser,
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(my_password)}
}
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", myhost, conf)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer conn.Close()
session, err := conn.NewSession()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
defer session.Close()
session.Stdout = os.Stdout
session.Stderr = os.Stderr
session.Stdin = os.Stdin

modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
    ssh.ECHO: 0
    ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400,
    ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400
}
if err := session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes); err != nil {
    return err
}
if err = session.Shell(); err != nil {
    return err
}

return session.Wait()
```

I've tried this with term values other than `xterm`: `screen-256color` and `vt100`.

For the record - in the real code, instead of just a call to `session.Wait()`, I have a `for/select` loop that catches various signals to the process and sends them on to the `Session`.

Comment: Have you tried disabling  `ECHOCTL` terminal mode?

Comment: @EmilDavtyan that fixed it! Now to understand why.

Comment: @Cerales Please remember to answer your own question and accept the answer :)

Comment: @Cerales I posted my comment as an answer, so you can mark this answered.

Comment: @Cera: What signals were you waiting for in you `for/select`? What did you do with them when you got them? I can't seem to get `SIGINT` (`CTRL+C`) to work the way I expect.

Comment: @YevgeniyBrikman I need to expand the implementation to handle every signal specified in the RFC, but for the moment I'm just handling SIGINT and SIGQUIT. When I get them I pass them into session.Signal().

Comment: @Cera: For some reason, `session.Signal()` never worked for me. However, see my new response below for a fully-working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `ECHOCTL` terminal mode.

```
modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
    ssh.ECHO: 0,
    ssh.ECHOCTL: 0,
    ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400,
    ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400
}
```

Comment: This fails to work for me.  I still see character escape codes and autocomplete doesn't work.

Comment: I've set `ssh.ECHOCTL` to 0 in my code and still see control characters when I use the arrow keys. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18):

The `ssh.ECHO: 0` and `ssh.ECHOCTL: 0` settings didn't work for me. For other people that ran into this issue, below is the rough code it took to get a fully working interactive terminal with the Go ssh library:

```
config := return &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User: "username",
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password("password")},
}

client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", "12.34.56.78:22", config)
if err != nil { ... }
defer client.Close()

session, err := client.NewSession()
if err != nil { ... }
defer session.Close()

session.Stdout = os.Stdout
session.Stderr = os.Stderr
session.Stdin = os.Stdin

modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
    ssh.ECHO:          1,     // enable echoing
    ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400, // input speed = 14.4kbaud
    ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, // output speed = 14.4kbaud
}

fileDescriptor := int(os.Stdin.Fd())

if terminal.IsTerminal(fileDescriptor) {
    originalState, err := terminal.MakeRaw(fileDescriptor)
    if err != nil { ... }
    defer terminal.Restore(fileDescriptor, originalState)

    termWidth, termHeight, err := terminal.GetSize(fileDescriptor)
    if err != nil { ... }

    err = session.RequestPty("xterm-256color", termHeight, termWidth, modes) 
    if err != nil { ... }
}

err = session.Shell()
if err != nil { ... }

// You should now be connected via SSH with a fully-interactive terminal
// This call blocks until the user exits the session (e.g. via CTRL + D)
session.Wait()
```

Note that all keyboard functionality (tab completion, up arrow) and signal handling (`CTRL + C`, `CTRL + D`) works correctly with the setup above.

Comment: So basically the problem is that `os.Stdin` is being buffered somehow? Thanks for this btw, I was getting really frustrated trying to figure out how to solve this problem.